# options for managing ActiveMailer generated queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

An application, hosted as the only application on a server, will be handling e-mails for large numbers of users who will launch groups of mailings.  Most other processing by the application is not very intense.

While the volumes of mails will not be massive, they are important ≈ in the thousands per day. Mails will mostly be sent as individual items following an action that involves multiple mail recepients; a lag will occur between individual items and within sub-groups of the mail recipients.

In other words, each mail can have a calculation as to the time when it should be issued.

There are multiple options for handling queues, which I would group into two categories.
a) RAM-based objects.  These have the disadvantage of losing the queues if something happens to the server.
b) database-based objects.  These require more processing. (I can only think of a mechanism whereby the mails are stored with their time release and a cron job (scheduler gem) check every minute for unreleased mails and where a datetime is < `Time.now`, sending them off and modifying the mail's 'released' attribute)

Not having experience with any of the queuing options, my question is based on your experience, which option and ActiveJob adapters (or non!) makes the most sense given the context, while containing complexity?

Comment: a): in-memory queue can be lost, but your tasks will mark the emails when successfully sent. So if a queue fails because you lost your memory state, the next spawned task should pickup the unsent email and sent them at this time. Make this task run every 5 minutes with Resque, setup good validations for the email _before sending it_ (as save time) and a max send retry logic + notifier if max retries reached, and you should have a pretty robust mailing scheduler app.